# What happens if I install updates without checking for new updates first?

Tags: apt, update-manager

Let's say I open the Update Manager, and my package list is a couple of days old, or I do `apt-get upgrade` without doing an `apt-get update` first, what is the result of this?

If there have been updates since I last did a 'check' in the Update Manager, do I not get the latest version?  Or do I simply not get updates on packages which had not updates at the time of my last check?

Answer (score 5):

`apt-get update` updates your local copy of the software catalog, and `apt-get upgrade` installs the new updates. So if you didn't update your local software catalog, you may not get latest updates (you will get updates from the previous update check).

Comment: Does that mean the server keeps a history of versions on there? Not just the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a good [community-sourced HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) on this.

The repository keeps track of what the latest version of a package is, but your host has to get that information so it can pull the latest version. When you `apt-get update` you're pulling a fresh copy of the list of all available packages, not just the ones you installed. Running `apt-get upgrade` uses your local copy of the list, compared against the list of what you have installed, to decide what packages to download from the repository.

Whenever you run `apt-get upgrade`, it uses the current (i.e. last downloaded) local copy of the package list to make decisions against. To make sure your local copy is fresh, you should run `apt-get update` before upgrading, and after adding any new repository location.

In most cases (see the link), it's a good idea to use `apt-get dist-upgrade` instead of `apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: what does apt-get dist-upgrade do?

Comment: `dist-upgrade` do the same of `upgrade` (install newer version of packages). But, also, can changing dependecies and remove packages. For this reson you can think about `upgrade` as a "safe-upgrade" and `dist-upgrade` as a full-upgrade.